# The counterfeit coin

Tags: logical-deduction, optimization

You have 9 coins. One of the nine is counterfeit. The counterfeit coin can be distinguished by weight - it is heavier than the rest.

Using a balance scale only **twice**, find the counterfeit coin.

Comment: I think I've seen this puzzle here somewhere.

Comment: Which is already a duplicate's duplicate btw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ternary search.

> Split into groups of 3. Call them first3group, second3group,
>  third3group.
>
> Now weigh first3group vs second3group. 
>  If first test shows equal weights, the heavy coin is in third3group.
>  Split third3group and weigh 2.   Where one is heavier, QED, otherwise,
>  it is the non-weighed one, QED.
>
> Else take the heavier group of 3 and do a similar exercise as
>  described above when left with 3, 1 of which is heavier.

QED